# Imprimir string de forma reversa

Tags: c#, .net, string, exceção

Por que eu não consigo imprimir essa `string` de forma reversa? Eu sei que há possibilidade de usar outra forma mais simples, porém quero entender o erro.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string frase = "Diego lima de Aquino";

     for(int i = frase.Length; i>=0; i--)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(frase[i]);
     }

     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Erro:

> ```
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
> HResult=-2146233080
> Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
> Source=mscorlib
> StackTrace:
>     at System.String.get_Chars(Int32 index)
>     at AppNoPrompt_1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Diegolaquino\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AppNoPrompt_1\AppNoPrompt_1\Program.cs:line 20
>     at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>     at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
> InnerException:
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esse é bem simples resolver. Não pode começar pelo `Length`. Essa propriedade é o tamanho do *array* (uma *string* é um *array* de caracteres). Como ele começa no 0 ele termina no `Length - 1`. Veja:

```
10 posições       | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | Length é 10
Começando em zero | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9  | a última posição é 9
```

Assim funciona:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        string frase = "Diego lima de Aquino";
        for (int i = frase.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) WriteLine(frase[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uprOR0). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KUqKLr). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/JustOneChar.cs).

Answer (score 11):

O erro está na declaração do **i**

```
int i = frase.Length
```

**Problema**

`frase.Length` retorna a quantidade de itens dentro do array.

`frase[i]`, começa no index `0`.

Por exemplo 5 itens:

```
frase.Length == 5
frase[0] até frase[4] // frase[5] só existiria se houvesse 6 elementos
```

Para resolver este problema basta diminuir 1 na declaração do `i`

```
for(int i = frase.Length - 1; i>=0; i--)
{
     Console.WriteLine(frase[i]);
}
```

ou

```
for(int i = frase.Length ; i>=1; i--)
{
     Console.WriteLine(frase[i-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Porque, o `frase.Length` tem que tirar **1**, sendo o `array` iniciado com **0**, o `frase.Length` retorna a quantidade de posições, e por isso `frase.Length - 1`

```
for(int i = frase.Length - 1; i>=0; i--)
{
     Console.WriteLine(frase[i]);
}
```

[***Exemplo***](http://ideone.com/fork/lRst7L)

Answer (score 4):

A exceção (**`IndexOutOfRangeException`**) foi lançada, pois você tentou acessar uma posição que não existe na string.

No seguinte trecho:

```
int i = frase.Length
```

Para resolver o problema, você deve iniciar a variável `i` com o valor `frase.Length - 1;`

Exemplo:

Um vetor de 5 elementos possuí as seguintes posições: **0, 1, 2, 3, 4**. Não existe a posição 5(que é quantidade total de elementos da estrutura de dados).

Answer (score 4):

Curto e grosso:

```
var reverso = new string(frase.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
```